# On the netbook edition (Unity), firefox is taking up full screen, covering menu and its own controls

Tags: 10.10, unity, firefox

On my Dell mini with 10.10 netbook edition, I have run into a problem where firefox covers the whole screen and there is no way to get to any other windows except by minimizing.  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> does not allow me to move or resize. Rebooting did not help. I ended up removing the `.mozilla` directory which solved it, but lost all my settings. In case it matters, I'm using 2 monitors. Any info on this?

Comment: Try running firefox in safe mode (firefox -safe-mode) with your old profile if you haven't irrevocably removed it. There might be a conflicting addon or preferences.

Comment: Have any of the answers solved your problem?

Comment: @djeikyb, I haven't run into it again

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do with any window that has important bits below or above the screen edge is hold down <kbd>alt</kbd> while click and dragging with your left mouse button. It will let you drag the window around wherever you need. You can also resize by holding down <kbd>alt</kbd> while click and dragging with your right mouse button.

I suspect that you'll be fine once you resize Firefox down to something reasonable. After that, feel free to maximize the window or resize normally.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that you previously went into full-screen mode (F11), and then exited from Firefox.

There appears to have been a bug, where the full-screen size is remembered by Firefox, but not not that it was in full-screen mode.

Comment: Would that survive closing the app (and even rebooting)?

Comment: @SpashHit I wouldn't have thought so, but it does describe the other symptoms. Maybe Firefox saves FullScreen mode setting, for kiosk usage? Unless you saved your old profile, we're not really going to be able to get to the bottom of the problem anyway.

Comment: Interesting - I just tried quiting (Ctrl-Q) from a FullScreen Firefox session. It didn't remember fullscreen mode, but it did remember that size - so it appeared as a normal window (memu etc weren't on auto-hide), but all the window chrome and Gnome system bars were covered.

Comment: There might be a bug there even if it wasn't your problem.